# Finding kernel and image of a linear transformation, given eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

**Problem:** Consider the linear transformation $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ with eigenvalues $-1, 0$ and $1$ and the corresponding eigenvectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$. Determine $\text{ker}(T)$ and $\text{Im}(T)$.

**Attempt at solution:** In general we have $D = P^{-1} A P$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues, $P$ is the matrix with columns the corresponding eigenvectors, and $A$ is the matrixrepresentation of $T$ with respect to some basis. Hence $A = PDP^{-1}$. Now the kernel of $T$ is the nullspace of the matrix $A$, while the image of $T$ is the columnspace of $A$. I'm not sure how to solve this problem, because we are not given any specific eigenvectors. So how could we ever find $P^{-1}$? Since $0$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, $A$ is singular. But what does that say about the nullspace and columnspace of $A$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you name one vector in the kernel, a vector that is surely sent to 0, given what you've been told?

Comment: Well, for sure the eigenvector $v_2$ is in the kernel of $T$, since $T(v_2) = 0 v_2 = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible strategy:

Note that the dimension of $\operatorname{im}(T)$ equals the rank of $A$ and hence the rank of $D$ since conjugate matices have same rank. What is the rank of $D$? Hence, what is the dimension of $\operatorname{im}(T)$? Given the eigenvectors corresponding to the distinct non-zero eigenvalues, what are obvious independent elements of $\operatorname{im}(T)$?
Further, how are the dimensions of $\operatorname{im}(T)$ and $\operatorname{ker}(T)$ related? Hence, given that $0$ is an eigenvalue, what is $\operatorname{ker}(T)$?

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Rank of $D$ equals $2$. So dimension of the image of $T$ is also $2$. From the dimension theorem we have $\dim(\mathbb{R}^3) = \dim(ker(T)) + \dim(Im(T))$. So the dimension of the kernel must equal $1$. But what can be a basis for these spaces?

Comment: If $v$ is an eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $0$, then $Av=0$, right? What does this tell you about a possible basis for $ker(T)$? Similarly, if $v_1$ and $v_{-1}$ are eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues $\pm 1$, then what?

Comment: So I think the vector $v_2$ must be basis for the kernel. Furthermore, since $\dim(Im(T)) = 2$, we have that $v_1$ and $v_3$ form a basis for the image of $T$?

Comment: That's right...but you need to prove that they're linearly independent. I suggest that you suppose that $av_1 + bv_{-1} = 0$ and see whether you can prove that $a = b = 0$.

Comment: Eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are independent.